# RecipientList Apache Camel EIP

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to use the RecipientList pattern in Camel but I think I may be missing the point. The following code only displays one entry to the screen:

```
@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("direct:start").recipientList(bean(MyBean.class, "buildEndpoint"))
                    .streaming()
                    .process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            System.out.println(exchange.getExchangeId());
                        }
                    });
        }
    };
}

public static class MyBean {
    public static String[] buildEndpoint() {
        return new String[] { "exec:ls?args=-la", "exec:find?args=."};
    }
}
```

I also tried just returning a comma-delimited string from the buildEndpoint() method and using tokenize(",") in the expression of the recipientList() component definition but I still got the same result. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

That is expected, the recipient list sends a copy of the same message to X recipients. The processor you do afterwards is doing *after* the recipient lists is done, and therefore is only executed once.

Comment: I totally understand that but what happened to all the messages emitted from the recipientList endpoints? It looks like only the last endpoint made it's way into the final processor.

Comment: yeah they are aggregated, you can use a custom aggregation strategy.